# convert data written in lineedit to integer in python

Tags: python

I want to know how to extract integer data written in lineedit to a variable as integer. I have used a validator to restrict to integer data in qLineEdit; how can I get integer data stored in variable?

Below is what I tried:

```
    self.age = QtGui.QLabel("Age")
    self.ageEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit() 
    self.ageEdit.setValidator(QtGui.QIntValidator(self.ageEdit)) 

    pAge = self.ageEdit.text()
    pAge1 = integer(pAge)
```

but I am getting an error. Please can anyone correct me, where am I going wrong?

Comment: name 'integr' not defined as error

Comment: sorry! i didnt get your question?

Comment: Couldn't you *edit* your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no builtin function `integer`, but [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
>>> integer('1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'integer' is not defined
>>> int('1')
1
```